# Shell Method of solid generated by solid enclosed by $y=1/4x^3+2$ ,$ y=2-x$, and $x=2$ about $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

The shell method is confusing to me, so can someone please help me out.

Find the volume of a solid generated by rotating the region enclosed by $y=\frac{1}{4} x^3 +2$ , $y=2-x$, and $x=2$ about the $y$-axis. 
Thanks.

Comment: start by drawing a picture to work out the height of a typical element

Comment: Did you mean $y=\frac{1}{4} x^2 +2$ or $y=\frac{1}{4} x^3 +2$?

Comment: I meant x^3, ill fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a typical rectangle as in the picture, when it is rotated around $y$-axis we get a shell of volume $dV$ given by
$dV=2\pi x \left[\frac{1}{4}x^3+2-(2-x)\right]dx$

[image]

The volume you are looking for can be found as
$$V=\int_0^2 2\pi x \left[\frac{1}{4}x^3+2-(2-x)\right]dx$$

Comment: why do you use x^2, I would think you would just use 2* pi * x instead of pi * x^2

Comment: also thanks for creating a visual

Comment: also, dont think i did it right, because i got 228.81 haha

Comment: @Kemosabe It was a mistake, I have corrected it.

Comment: Sick thanks. Great answer